# Pandas barh plot part of plot not showing

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I am using the following code to generate a barh plot with data stored in a pandas dataframe. Problem is that part of the first bar is not showing and I'm not sure how to address that. Here is the code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax2 = ax.twiny()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
s = StringIO("""name     amount     price
A     40929   4066443
B     93904   9611272
C    188349  19360005
D    248438  24335536
E    205622  18888604
F    140173  12580900
G     76243   6751731
H     36859   3418329
I     29304   2758928
J     39768   3201269
K     30350   2867059""")
df = pd.read_csv(s, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
df.plot(x = 'name', y = 'price', kind = 'barh', ax = ax, color = 'steelblue', width = 0.4, position = 0)
df.plot(x = 'name', y = 'amount', kind = 'barh', ax = ax2, color = 'salmon', width = 0.4, position = 1)
```

and here is how the plot looks like:

[image]

as you can see, part of plot for name `K` is not showing properly. How could I add some sort of a margin to create space between that axis and the plot itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to adjust the upper y-limit:

```
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_ylim((ylim[0], ylim[1]+0.4))
```

Output:
[image]